# A graph-theoretic optimization problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph with vertex set $V=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and edge set $E$. I associate to each vertex of $G$ a (positive) weight $w_i\in\mathbb{R}$, and denote by $w=[w_1 \dots w_n]^\top$ the vector containing all weights. Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times |E|}$ denote the incidence matrix of the graph $G$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^{|E|}$ be a vector with positive entries.

I'm interested in the following (linear) problem:
\begin{align*}
&\max_{\{w_i\}} w_n - w_1 \\
& \text{s.t. }\ \  B^\top w \le b
\end{align*}

Specifically:

> Is this problem related to some "standard" graph-theoretic problem? Are there efficient algorithms to solve it?

Comment: The objective function is unclear to me - are you maximizing $w_n - w_1$, or the maximum of $w_i - w_1$? (the latter is not linear, of course)

Comment: @DánielG. I'm trying to maximize $w_n-w_1$ over all weights $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by incidence matrix you mean its directed version (the one that has $\pm 1$ entries as opposed to just $1$-s).

Your linear program is dual to the linear formulation of the problem of finding a shortest $v_1v_n$ path with edge weights given by $b$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#/Linear_programming_formulation). Its solutions are sometimes called "feasible potentials". After running Dijkstra's algorithm starting from $v_1$, the "tentative distance values" given by the algorithm form an optimal solution.